# Pipe the output of gshuf to mv (Bash / OSX)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, command-line-interface, shuffle

I'm having a hard time piping the output of a gshuf command to a move command. I have a set of folders with between 50 and 1,000 files. I need to randomly select a subset of them and move them to another folder. I have read of couple of solutions on that topic but many of the flags required to pass that properly don't seem to be in OSX (I have installed gshuf via Homebrew since it's not by default on OSX).

Here's what I have so far (selects 10 random files in the current directory and try to move them to my destination folder but it doesn't work):

```
gshuf -zen10 * | xargs mv -i my_destination_folder/
```

I think I'm not using xargs and / or mv flags properly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The destination directory must be the last argument with BSD (macOS) `mv`; GNU `mv` has a `-t target` option which means that the directory can go before the files to be removed.  If you're only moving 10 files and they don't have spaces etc in the names, then `mv $(gshuf -zen10 *) my_destination_folder/` should do the job.  If you have spaces or newlines in the names, then we may have to think again.  If you were moving thousands of files, you'd have to worry about command line length, etc.  Another option is to use Homebrew to install the GNU file utilities (`mv` specifically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destination directory must be the last argument with POSIX [`mv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) and also with BSD (macOS) `mv`.  GNU `mv` has a `-t target` option which means that the directory can go before the files to be removed.

```
/opt/gnu/bin/mv -t my_destination_folder …
```

If you're only moving 10 files and they don't have spaces or other special characters in the names (if they stick with the POSIX [portable file name character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282)), then you should be able to do the job with:

```
mv $(gshuf -zen10 *) my_destination_folder/
```

If you have spaces or other special characters in the names, then we have to think again — amongst other things, it'll be necessary to know what the `-zen10` option(s) do with `gshuf`.  If the `-z` means 'output null terminated data instead of newlines' (not uncommon in the world of GNU utilities), then your `xargs` command was missing the `-0` option.

You might need to do something modestly intricate like:

```
gshuf -zen10 * | xargs -0 -J % mv % my_destination_dir/
```

If you were moving thousands of files, you'd have to worry about command line length, etc.  Another option is to use Homebrew to install the GNU file utilities (`mv` specifically) and then use that variant of `mv` and the `-t` option:

```
gshuf -zen10 * | xargs mv -t my_destination_dir/
```

(Again, you might need a `-0` option to `xargs`.)

---

#### After finding the manual for GNU `shuf`

Digging out the manual page for GNU [`shuf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#shuf-invocation) from the Core Utils manual, we find that `-z` is indeed for null terminated output 'lines'.  So, `xargs -0` is crucial.  And the option:

```
gshuf -zen10 * | xargs -0 -J % mv % my_destination_dir/
```

should indeed do the trick.  I'd probably add `-t` to `xargs` while experimenting to monitor what it does.

Comment: Thanks the command `mv $(gshuf -zen10 *) my_destination_folder/` works when I pick a single random file (i.e. with `-zen1`). But, I realize that the output of the `gshuf` command with `-zen10` doesn't create spaces between file names. My output is something like `filename_22.tiffilename_52.tiffilename_127.tif` etc. instead of  `filename_22.tif filename_52.tif filename_127.tif`. I suspect this is why it cannot be used with `mv`

Comment: `gshuf -zen10 * | xargs -0 -J % mv % my_destination_dir/` works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: `mv $(...) ...` is a bad idea, because the result of the command substitution is subject to word-splitting and pathname expansion, possibly preventing certain file names from being passed correctly as arguments to `mv`.

Comment: Yes, I said more or less as much.  If the file names use the portable file name character set, it is OK.  If not, it isn't.  I've now added an explicit statement about portable file name character set and a link to where POSIX 2008 defines it.